# Binary Tree Get Bottom extreme Left or Right

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary-tree

I have a table that stores a binary tree as follows:

```
Id  ParentId Level Placement 
47   -1       0     0
23   47       1     0
86   47       1     1
5    23       2     0
29    23      2     1
68    86      2     0
8    5      3     1
31    29      3     1
67    68      3     0
.
.
.
```

Using MSSQL
now, I need to get BottomLeft of a given id, in this example, for 47 its bottom left is 5
and I need to get the bottom right of a given id,  in this example for 47 its bottom right is 86

Bottom left or right is not the lowest level left or right, but extreme outside left or right leaf.

**How do I write an sql that gives me a bottom left or right for a given Id?**

Above placement of 0 is left and 1 is right

[image]

Comment: I have trouble understanding why 8 is not bottom left and 62 bottom right.  if 99 existed would it be bottom right? and if 6 existed would it be bottom left?  I see nothing in the data which has the left right.... or would just using a min/max work on the ID?

Comment: @xQbert to get bottom left of 47 you have to keep traversing only to your left child and never go to id on right side. same for Right

Comment: gotcha now.  Placement 0 indicates left 1 indicates right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use recursive query

here is example for **leftmost** query, you can easy change it to rightmost query by changing the placement to 1

```
with leftmost(ParentId,Id,depth) as (
    select t.Id,t.Id,0
    from #BinaryTree t
    union all
    select lm.parentid,t.Id,lm.depth+1
    from leftmost lm
        join #BinaryTree t on lm.Id = t.ParentId
    where t.Placement = 0 -- change to 1 for right most
)
select top 1 Id
from leftmost
where parentid = 47 --replace with the id you query
order by depth desc
```

Comment: when i use parm DECLARE side INT = 0;
DECLARE searchId INT = 47 ;   this seems to run very very slow vs literal

Comment: it's SQL-SERVER optimization. you can try OPTION(RECOMPILE)

Answer (score 4):

Note:  The final where is commented out to illustrate the full hierarchy.

Create Demonstrative Table

```
Declare @YourTable table (Id int,Pt int, Level int, Placement int) 
Insert Into @YourTable values 
(47,-1, 0,0),
(23,47, 1,0),
(86,47, 1,1),
(5 ,23, 2,0),
(29,23, 2,1),
(68,86, 2,0),
(8 , 5, 3,1),
(31,29, 3,1),
(67,68, 3,0)
```

---

The SQL -

```
Declare @Top    int = null         --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 5
Declare @MaxLvl int = 99
Declare @Nest varchar(25) = '   '  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteHB (Seq,ID,Pt,Lvl,Title,Placement) as (
    Select  Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by ID) as varchar(500))
           ,ID   
           ,Pt   
           ,Lvl=1
           ,Title =concat('Item ',ID)
           ,Placement 
     From   @YourTable Where (Pt=-1 and isnull(@Top,-1) =-1) or (ID=@Top and isnull(@Top,0) <>0)
     Union  All
     Select Seq  = cast(concat(cteHB.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by cteCD.ID)) as varchar(500))
           ,cteCD.ID 
           ,cteCD.Pt
           ,cteHB.Lvl+1
           ,Title = concat('Item ',cteCD.ID) 
           ,cteCD.Placement
     From   @YourTable cteCD 
     Join   cteHB on cteCD.Pt = cteHB.ID and cteHB.Lvl+1<=@MaxLvl and cteCD.Placement=0)

,cteR1 as (Select Seq,ID,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteHB)
,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.ID )
Select B.R1  
      ,C.R2
      ,A.ID
      ,A.Pt
      ,A.Lvl
      ,Title = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl) + A.Title
      ,A.Placement
 From cteHB A
 Join cteR1 B on A.ID=B.ID
 Join cteR2 C on A.ID=C.ID
 --Where R1=R2 
 Order By B.R1
```

Returns

```
R1  R2  ID  Pt  Lvl    Title                Placement
1   9   47  -1  1      Item 47              0
2   6   23  47  2         Item 23           0
3   4   5   23  3            Item 5         0
4   4   8   5   4               Item 8      1
5   6   29  23  3            Item 29        1
6   6   31  29  4               Item 31     1
7   9   86  47  2         Item 86           1
8   9   68  86  3            Item 68        0
9   9   67  68  4               Item 67     0
```

Comment: i want my output to be 5 not all this details when searching for bottom left

Comment: @JustinHomes modified sql to include "and cteCD.Placement=0"

Comment: Where is the input of Id? becasue a table can have multiple binary tree like this and even for this tree if i give child nodes like 29 it should give bottom right of 40 and bottom left of 29 itself

Comment: @JustinHomes  to set the top ---   Declare [at]Top int = null   --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 5