# How to get extreme left node or extreme right node of binary tree?

Tags: php, mysql, binary-tree

My DB structure is [image]

I have written down all the queries to handle Binary tree only left most node finding is pending. also i got solution for this on stackoverflow but that is for SQL but i want this in Mysql here is the link [SQL Link solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251294/binary-tree-get-bottom-extreme-left-or-right). can anybody change it for me in MYSQL.

here is my MYSQL stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getLeftMost`(IN `iNode` INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE left_id int;
DECLARE prev_id int;
SET prev_id=iNode;


SELECT lnode into left_id from binTree where nodeid=iNode;

CREATE TEMPORARY table IF NOT EXISTS temp_table as (select * from binTree where 1=0);
TRUNCATE table temp_table;

WHILE  left_id <> 0 DO
INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT * FROM binTree where nodeid=prev_id;
SET prev_id=left_id;
SELECT lnode into left_id from binTree where nodeid=prev_id;
END WHILE;

SELECT lnode as `leaf_node` FROM temp_table order by nodeid desc limit 0,1;

END
```

Thanks

Comment: May I suggest you first search for recursive query with MySQL, then ask our help. We are not here to make your job, but to give a hand.

Comment: Already tried but that will take so much time when depth of tree increase like if there is 1 lac records then its taking so much time

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: please submit question with your valuable efforts.

Comment: please check i have edit this wtih my written code

Comment: This is not a chat, people respond when they have time. It doesn't look like your procedure even touches the parent. So how could this be the problem?

Comment: This is recursive way to get left node but it takes so much time when  no of records become so higher